# Timer like custom control int .NET

Tags: c#, custom-controls

How can I create a custom control in C# that in design time act like a Timer and in runtime be invisible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derive your class from Component, instead of Control

[Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx)

Comment: How can I read property ParentForm as with Control base class?